# "Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied" error on adding data to my Sql Data using C#

Tags: c#, sql

For my Uni Project and we are required to use 3-Tier architecture and Stored Procedures. (i.e: Data-access Layer, Business Class Layer and Presentation Layer)

The goal is to add data to the database in C# and then be able to show that data in the desired Form.

I am able to Load hard coded data from the Database and view it in the form Data grid perfectly fine but adding seems to be the issue. Also the Stored Procedure says it works is SSMS.

This is the exact error that i am getting:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'us_InsertSupervisors' expects parameter '@SupervisorID', which was not supplied.

Here is my Stored Procedure made to INSERT the Data:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[us_InsertSupervisors]
@SupervisorID varchar(10),
@SupervisorFirstName varchar(50),
@SupervisorSurname varchar(50),
@SupervisorCellNo varchar(50),
@SupervisorStatus varchar(10)

INSERT INTO SupervisorTable(SupervisorID, SupervisorFirstName, SupervisorSurname, SupervisorCellNo, SupervisorStatus) 
Values(@SupervisorID, @SupervisorFirstName, @SupervisorSurname, @SupervisorCellNo, @SupervisorStatus )
```

Then my Data-Access Layer method us to retrieve the Stored Procedure:

```
 public int InsertSupervisor(string supervisorID, string supervisorFirstName, string supervisorSurname, string supervisorCellNo, string supervisorStatus)
    {
        if (dbConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            dbConn.Open();

        string sqlinsert = "us_InsertSupervisors";
        dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorID", supervisorID);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorFirstName", supervisorFirstName);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorSurname", supervisorSurname);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorCellNo", supervisorCellNo);
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorStatus", supervisorStatus);


        int x = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return x;

    }
```

The Business Class Layer:

```
    class Supervisor
{
    DataAccessLayer dl = new DataAccessLayer();
    public string SupervisorID { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorSurname { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorCellNo { get; set; }
    public string SupervisorStatus { get; set; }

    public DataTable GetAllSupervisorNames()
    {
        return dl.GetAllSupervisorNames();
    }

    public DataTable GetAllSupervisors()
    {
        return dl.GetAllSupervisors();
    }

    public int InsertSupervisor(string SupervisorID, string SupervisorFirstName, string SupervisorSurname, string SupervisorCellNo, string SupervisorStatus)
    {
        return dl.InsertSupervisor(SupervisorID, SupervisorFirstName, SupervisorSurname, SupervisorCellNo, SupervisorStatus);
    }
}
```

And the Presentation Layer:

```
  public partial class frmSupervisor : Form
{
    Supervisor su = new Supervisor();
    public frmSupervisor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmSupervisor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvSupervisors.DataSource = su.GetAllSupervisors();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        su.InsertSupervisor(txtSupervisorID.Text, txtSupervisorFirstName.Text, txtSupervisorSurname.Text, txtSupervisorCellNumber.Text, txtSupervisorStatus.Text);
    }
```

C# directs me to this line in the Data-Access Layer (InsertSupervisor) Method:

```
        int x = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing the `AddWithValue` to `Add`, like this: `dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = supervisorID;` Do this for all parameters. [Why?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: First of all, please do not use `AddWithValue` method, use `Commands.Add()`.

Comment: As `dbCmd` is not declared within `InsertSupervisor` you are presumably maintaining a higher scoped instance of it?  If that's the case and your using it in multiple places you need to remove any previously added params with `dbCmd.Parameters.Clear()` before adding new ones for a different SP  (Or just create a local as needed).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried your format, it still came up with the same error. I am still going to use the format as your linked article highlights some good points.

Comment: Is `supervisorID` `null`, by any chance? If so, you should be sending `DBNull.Value` to the database. Try `dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = supervisorID ?? DBNull.Value`

Comment: @AlexK. Yes it was declared in the higher scope. I added  
    dbCmd.Parameters.Clear() to the necessary place and still got the error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it is not supposed to be null but I inserted your code and still got the error

Comment: from c# supervisorid will be null then , in stored procedure make supervisorid varidable as null. ex: @SupervisorID varchar(10) null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after our conversation in the comments I've looked at your code once again to see what we've missed, and suddenly this popped up:

```
dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, dbConn);
```

Your `dbCmd` command type is now `CommandType.Text`, since it's the default value.
Change the order of these two rows and you should be fine.

However, While I'm writing an answer, it's probably best to go over a couple more things to change in your code:

1. You are using fields for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. This is bad practice.
   Best practice is to use local variables inside a using statement for both - not only because they both implement the `IDisposable` interface, but also because ADO.Net implements a connection pool, and by disposing the instance of `SqlConnection` you are returning the connection to the pool.
2. Using `AddWithValue`. I know we've covered it in the comments but no answer would be complete without dealing with this.

So a better code would be something like this:

```
public int InsertSupervisor(string supervisorID, string supervisorFirstName, string supervisorSurname, string supervisorCellNo, string supervisorStatus)
{
    string sqlinsert = "us_InsertSupervisors";

    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlinsert, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = supervisorID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorFirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = supervisorFirstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorSurname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = supervisorSurname;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorCellNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = supervisorCellNo;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupervisorStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = supervisorStatus;        
            con.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Implemented the first solution and that fixed the error and explained a number of other problems that i had throughout the application. I also modified all the code in my Data-Access Layer to follow Best Practices standards. I appreciate your help